# Jackson: prevent field serialization at runtime

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson for converting java object to JSON.
I came across @JsonIgnore annotation that can prevent serialisation of a property. This is specially helpful in preventing circular reference errors when dealing with bi-directional relationships. Is there a way to do this at run-time.
For example I have a bi-directional one to many many to on relationship.

```
Class A{

private List<B> listOfBs;

}

Class B{

private A a;

}
```

Suppose I want to serialize object of A together with the list of B's
the I'll use @JsonIgnore annotation on A's getter in B like this.

```
Class B{

private A a;

@JsonIgnore
public A getA(){
return a;

}

}
```

but if at the same time I need to serialize an object of B together with the related A object in it, is it possible to tell a runtime, when to serialize A in B and when not to.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use views: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Comment: This looks promising. Though not very clean but it should do the trick I guess.
Will let you know once I do a POC.

Comment: You can also take a look at [the Jackson's bi-directional references](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences).